# como pintar la informacion del archivo de pythpon en el reporte xml

Tags: python, mvc, xml, odoo, report

como puedo pasar la informacion de l modelo de odoo que tengo en python al reporte que estoy diseñando en xml ya que en si estoy abstrallendo infomracion especifica del modelo ya que el modelo lo dividi por secciones para obtener infoormes avanzados con informacion especifica pero esoty algo confundido de como pasarle la infomracion que esta recibiendo el archivo de python al archivo xml

Adjunto codigo pytohn:

````
```import json
   import io
   from xlsxwriter import workbook

  from odoo.tools import date_utils
  from odoo import fields, models,api
  from odoo.exceptions import UserError, ValidationError



 class Cantidades(models.TransientModel):
_name = "reporte_mti_cantidades_carta_porte"

  consignment_note_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='mti.carta.porte', string='Carta 
 Porte')
brand_number = fields.Float(string='Marcas y Números "1 /"')
number_lumbs = fields.Float(string='Bultos')
volume = fields.Float(string='Volumen')
gross_weight = fields.Float(string='Peso Bruto', digits='Product Price')
net_weight = fields.Float(string='Peso Neto')
volumetric_weight = fields.Float(string='Cubic Weight', digits=(20, 4))

def get_cantidades_report(self):
    data = {
        'consignment_note_id': self.consignment_note_id,
        'brand_number': self.brand_number,
        'number_lumbs': self.number_lumbs,
        'volume': self.volume,
        'gross_weight':self.gross_weight,
        'net_weight':self.net_weight,
        'volumetric_weight':self.volumetric_weight
    }
    return self.env.ref('mti_report_cp.cantidades').report_action(self, data=data)


 class ManyCard(models.AbstractModel):
_name = 'report.cantidades'

@api.model
def _get_report_values(self, docids, data=None):
    return {
        'doc:ids': docids,
        'doc_model': 'mti.carta.porte',
        'docs': self.env['mti.carta.porte'].search_read([('consignment_note_id', '==', data['consignment_note_id']),
                                                         ('brand_number', '==', data['brand_number'])],
                                                        ['consignment_note_id','brand_number','number_lumbs','volume','gross_weight','net_weight','volumetric_weight'])
    }```
````

asi es como tengo estrcuturado el modelo y toda la infomracion que recibe la tengo que pintar en un reporte en xml

Ajunto codigo xml:

````
```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
<template id="cantidades_report_view">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
        <t class="page">
            <div class="oe_structure"/>
            <center>
                <b>
                    <h3>Informe de cantidades de la carta de porte</h3>
                </b>
            </center>
            <table class="table table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>consignment_note_id</th>
                        <th>brand_number</th>
                        <th>number_lumbs</th>
                        <th>volume</th>
                        <th>gross_weight</th>
                        <th>net_weight</th>
                        <th>volumetric_weight</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr t-foreach="form" t-as="order">
                        
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
</odoo>```
````

y asi esta la estructura del reporte en te caso como informe avanzado o especifico como puedo pasale la informacion o que tendira que hacer para poder pasarle la informacion

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Para pasar la información del modelo de Odoo que está escrito en Python al archivo XML que estás utilizando para generar un reporte, puedes utilizar el método render_template de la clase ir.ui.view. Este método te permite reemplazar los valores de las variables del archivo XML con los valores de las variables del archivo Python.

Para utilizar el método render_template, primero debes importar la clase ir.ui.view en el archivo Python, y luego utilizar el método render_template para reemplazar los valores de las variables del archivo XML con los valores de las variables del archivo Python. Aquí te muestro un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacerlo:

```
import json
from odoo.tools import date_utils
from odoo import fields, models, api
from odoo.exceptions import UserError, ValidationError
from odoo.addons.ir.ui.view import ir_ui_view

class Cantidades(models.TransientModel):
    _name = "reporte_mti_cantidades_carta_porte"
    consignment_note_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='mti.carta.porte', string='Carta Porte')
    brand_number = fields.Float(string='Marcas y Números "1 /"')
    number_lumbs = fields.Float(string='Bultos')
    volume = fields.Float(string='Volumen')
    gross_weight = fields.Float(string='Peso Bruto', digits='Product Price')
    net_weight = fields.Float(string='Peso Neto')
    volumetric_weight = fields.Float(string='Cubic Weight', digits=(20, 4))

    def get_cantidades_report(self):
        # Crea un diccionario con los valores de las variables del archivo Python
        data = {
            'consignment_note_id': self.consignment_note_id,
            'brand_number': self.brand_number,
            'number_lumbs': self.number_lumbs,
            'volume': self.volume,
            'gross_weight':self.gross_weight,
            'net_weight':self.net_weight,
            'volumetric_weight':self.volumetric_weight
        }

        # Carga el archivo XML que contiene la plantilla del reporte
        xml_file = open('cantidades_report_view.xml', 'r')
        xml_template = xml_file.read()
        xml_file.close()

        # Utiliza el método render_template de la clase ir.ui.view para reemplazar
        # los valores de las variables del archivo XML con los valores de las
        # variables del archivo Python
        xml_report = ir_ui_view.render_template(xml_template, data)

        # Guarda el reporte generado en un archivo
        report_file = open('cantidades_report.xml', 'w')
        report_file.write(xml_report)
        report_file.close()

        # Devuelve el reporte generado como un archivo adjunto
        return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
            'url': 'cantidades_report.xml',
            'target': 'new',
        }
```

Esta Respuesta fue generada por chatGPT.

https://chat.openai.com/chat

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141532/discussion-on-answer-by-alejandro-gonzalez-como-pintar-la-informacion-del-archiv).